# How can I set up my Express API endpoint to return dynamic responses based on the URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-admin

I am working on a react-admin project that involves a connection to an express server through a data provider.

I have not been able to get sorting or pagination to work, and I understand that I have to make changes in my express API responses to get these features to work.

I wrote the code below to detect what the sort parameter is sending, in hopes that I could have a different API response depending on the sort URL.

I have been having a really hard time getting the sort and pagination features to work.  Please help if you can! TY

````
    usersRouter.get("/", addRAHeader, checkJwt, async (req, res) => {
      const user_id = req.query.sort
      console.log(user_id)
      if(req.query.sort === ["id","ASC"]) {
      try {
        connection.execute(
          // getUsers,
          getUsersASC,
          function(err, users, fields) {
            console.log("USERSDESC")
            res.status(200).json(users)
          }
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
      }
    }
    else if(req.query.sort === ["email","ASC"]) {
      try {
        connection.execute(
          // getUsers,
          getUsersASC,
          function(err, users, fields) {
            console.log("USERSASC")
            res.status(200).json(users)
          }
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
      }
    } else {
      try {
        connection.execute(
          // getUsers,
          getUsersASC,
          function(err, users, fields) {
            console.log("USERSELSE")
            res.status(200).json(users)
          }
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
      }
    }
    });```
````

Comment: Something like `(req.query.sort === ["id","ASC"]` will never work because `req.query.sort` will be a single string and thus will never match an array (actually nothing will match that array).  What exactly are you trying to do with that comparison?

Comment: Please show examples of multiple URLs with their query parameters that you want to use and then describe what code should execute for each URL.  Imagine you're writing a specification for a coder to implement.  Write it out in detail so we can very clearly see what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00. 

When I do a console.log of req.query.sort, I see ["id","ASC"] and so that’s why I was using thst in thr if statements

Comment: As I asked 15 hours ago, please show examples of the incoming URLs you wish to use with this code.  If you're not going to respond to clarifying questions, then we'll just leave and go help someone who is going to be responsive.  Your question is incomplete and you are not clarifying it.

Comment: I’m sorry about that.  Had a family member I was helping with some legal stuff,  gimme just a few min to get you those urls, thank you very very much for your response

Comment: ```http://localhost:3000/#/users?filter=%7B%7D&order=DESC&page=1&perPage=10&sort=email```

Here is an example of the URL when i click the 'sort by email' button. 

The url changes, but there doesn't seem to be a change in the response.  

My if statements arent working

Comment: What is the `#` doing in that URL?  That's not the URL that will get sent to the server.  Ok, I see you're using react, so probably something else is actually getting sent to the server.  And, that URL does not give you `["id","ASC"]` for `req.query.sort`.  That would only occur if there were two items in the query parameter with the same key like `?sort=id&sort=ASC`.  Without understanding the spec for what you're trying to support, it's pretty hard to know what server-side code to suggest.

Comment: I understand.  It looks like I have to work on my question asking abilities and gain a better understanding of this piece of software.  I am using react-admin and in their documentation for the getLIST function I am using.. the URL query looks like this:

```GET http://my.api.url/posts?sort=["email","ASC"]&range=[0, 24]&filter={"title":"bar"}```

Comment: Well, is `?sort=["email","ASC"]` how you want to do it in the URL or do you want to do something like `?sort=email&order=ASC`?  The latter is a lot easier to program with on the server.

Comment: I’m not sure where in react admin I would configure this.  I have no issue configuring it to to use seperate persmeters for sort and order… but I’m not sure where in react admin to control or change that.

Comment: If this is now a react question, I will bow out and I don't know anything about react.

Comment: lasif lasif in react-admin your sort parameters depend on the actual component configuration, as well as the dataprovider you are using. I have never seen sort like that, which leads me to believe that you have two items labeled sort in your react-admin component. typically one is called sort and the other is called order

Answer (score 1):

To begin with you can store two vars in single query variable sort. You can design your queryParams Like `/?sortBy=id&sortOrder=DESC`

Your express code might look like this

```
usersRouter.get("/", addRAHeader, checkJwt, async (req, res) => {
      const user_id = req.query.sort
      const sortBy = req.query.sortBy
      const sortOrder = req.query.sortOrder
      //if(req.query.sort === ["id","ASC"]) {
      if(sortBy === "id" && sortOrder === "ASC") 
      try {
        connection.execute(
          // getUsers,
          getUsersASC,
          function(err, users, fields) {
            console.log("USERSDESC")
            res.status(200).json(users)
          }
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
      }
    }
    // else if(req.query.sort === ["email","ASC"]) {
    else if(sortBy === "email" && sortOrder === "ASC") {
      try {
        connection.execute(
          // getUsers,
          getUsersASC,
          function(err, users, fields) {
            console.log("USERSASC")
            res.status(200).json(users)
          }
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
      }
    } else {
      try {
        connection.execute(
          // getUsers,
          getUsersASC,
          function(err, users, fields) {
            console.log("USERSELSE")
            res.status(200).json(users)
          }
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
      }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem.  Conceptually, the thing I was missing is that react-admin uses serverside sorting and pagination.

Once I realized that, I simply wrote some code in my express API endpoint that was able to properly receive the sort and filter parameters in the URL query, and then I used a querybuilder function to create a custom MySQL query that reflected those parameters.

```
usersRouter.get("/", addRAHeader, checkJwt,  async (req, res) => {   setTimeout(() => {
    const { sort, range, filter } = req.query
    if (filter || range || sort !== undefined) {
      parsedFilter = JSON.parse(filter).q
      parsedRange = JSON.parse(range)
      lowerRange = parsedRange[0]
      upperRange = parsedRange[1] + 1
      parsedSort = JSON.parse(sort)
      querySQL(queryBuilder(`${parsedSort[0]} ${parsedSort[1]}`, `${parsedRange[0]},${(upperRange - lowerRange)}`, parsedFilter), res)
    } else {
      querySQL(getUsers, res)
    }   }, 1000) });

function queryBuilder (orderByParam, limit=10, filter='') {   const query = `SELECT * FROM users Where email like '%${filter}' ORDER BY ${orderByParam} LIMIT ${limit};`   // console.log("QueryBuilt:", query)   return query  }

let querySQL = (query, res) => {
  try {
    connection.execute(
      query,
      function(err, users, fields) {
        res.status(200).json(users)
      }
    )
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({message:err});
  }
}
```

A combination of these functions above solved the issue for me.